# Comparing Cumulative Incidence Curves

Tags: survival, competing-risks

I have a dataset of about 1000 patients with cancer and I was interested at looking at competing events. I plotted out the cumulative incidence curves for deaths from cancer and deaths from other causes

[image]

The curves subjectively look very different, but I was wondering is there a statistical test that I could use to compare these curves? I've looked into Fine and Gray models as well as cause-specific hazard models, but seemingly those focus on evaluating the impact of specific covariates on the outcomes.

I've been using the `tidycmprsk` package as well as the `ggsurvfit` package in R. My code for the above curves is below

```r
cuminc(Surv(TTOS, status_cr) ~ 1, data = data) %>%
  ggcuminc(outcome = c("Death from other cause", 
                       "Death from cancer")) +
  ylim(c(0, 1)) + 
  labs(x = "Months") +
  add_risktable()
```

Comment: Bootstraped confidence intervals on the differences (because [analytic CIs are difficult for statistics which are products of conditional estimates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145418/why-is-estimating-the-standard-error-of-an-estimate-that-is-itself-the-product-o), which the cumulative incidence—in the sense of $1 - \widehat{S}(t)$—is an example of).

Comment: I have some thoughts on this problem [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/604264/28500). There's a problem in that the two cumulative incidence curves under competing risks aren't independent: a change in one necessarily means there is a change in the other. Bootstrapping, as @Alexis suggests, might be used if you have an appropriate statistic describing the differences between the curves, but I haven't thought that through carefully.